# SQLite is not assigning primary keys

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, schemaspy

I have a simple SQLite database created using sqlite3.exe (code is below). When I run it through SchemaSpy, it looks like there are no primary keys in my first three tables. I don't understand what is wrong with the CREATE TABLE statements in the first three tables.

**Code In:**

```
.open test1.db
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE META_E (E_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, E_Name TEXT, Region TEXT, Date DATE);

CREATE TABLE META_D (D_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Citation TEXT, is_used BOOLEAN);

CREATE TABLE META_G (Completion TEXT, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, Location TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));

CREATE TABLE P_ID_Main (Source_File TEXT, P_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, E_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, E_ID, D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (E_ID) REFERENCES META_E (E_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));

.dump
```

**Dump:**

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE META_E (E_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, E_Name TEXT, Region TEXT, Date DATE);
CREATE TABLE META_D (D_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Citation TEXT, is_used BOOLEAN);
CREATE TABLE META_G (Completion TEXT, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, Location TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));
CREATE TABLE P_ID_Main (Source_File TEXT, P_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, E_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, D_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, E_ID, D_ID), FOREIGN KEY (E_ID) REFERENCES META_E (E_ID), FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES META_D (D_ID));
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

**SchemaSpy:**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand what is wrong with the CREATE TABLE statements in
>   the first three tables.

I regard to the indexes there is nothing wrong with the CREATE TABLE statements. Rather it appears to be a shortfall of SchemaSpy.

SQLite isn't creating indexes as there is no need as the columns E_ID, D_ID (for both the META_D and META_G tables) are aliases of the **rowid** column, which could be considered as the MASTER index *(see link below)*.

In short the column's are in fact indexed but there is no need for SQLite to create an index as the index is built in (an exception is a special type of table a WITHOUT ROWID table).

As such the indexes won't appear in sqlite_master, as there is no need and it appears that SchemaSpy at least the way you have it configured, doesn't fully cater for SQLite.

You may wish to refere to [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)